# How to make hexagon shape image in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to make hexagon shape image like as below image but didn't find any perticular way to make it customized.

Here is the image: [image]

Suggest any library to make it possible in react-native.

Comment: I suggest you to read this article https://www.codedaily.io/tutorials/The-Shapes-of-React-Native

Comment: Clip path in react-native-skia seems to do what you're looking for. Here's the [example](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/group/#clip-path)

Comment: @AnwerSolangi It is just for view shape, not working in image.

Comment: @PhantomSpooks no path for hexagon here..

Comment: You'll have to either find a path for a hexagon or create your own im afraid

Answer (score 0):

So I thought that the usage of a hexagon path was so common that finding an existing one online would be a simple task, but searches proved to be fruitless so I decided to make a function that would make a regular hexagon Skia Path. I found a really cool [quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-find-the-coordinates-in-a-hexagon) answer on how to get the points any size hexagon(regular hexagon), and then I just connect the points:

```js
import {Skia} from "@shopify/react-native-skia";

function makeHexagonPath(size, offset) {
  const path = Skia.Path.Make();
  let [xOffset, yOffset] = offset || [0, 0];
  if (!size) size = 10;

  // https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-find-the-coordinates-in-a-hexagon
  const halfed = size / 2;
  const sqrt = (Math.sqrt(3) * size) / 2;
  const points = [
    [size, 0], //a
    [halfed, sqrt], //b
    [-halfed, sqrt], //c
    [-size, 0], //d
    [-halfed, -sqrt], //e
    [halfed, -sqrt], //f
  ].map(([x, y]) => [x + xOffset, y + yOffset]);
  console.log(points);
  path.moveTo(...points[0]);

  points.forEach((point) => path.lineTo(...point));
  path.close();
  return path;
}
```

With the `makeHexagonPath` function you draw a clipping of any size and use the offset parameter to move the hexagon to desired location:

```js
const imageSize = 200

export default function ClipImage({imageSrc}) {
  const image = useImage(imageSrc);
  const hexagonSize = imageSize / 2;
  const path = makeHexagonPath(hexagonSize, [hexagonSize, hexagonSize]);
  if (!image) return null;
  return (
    <Group clip={path}>
      /*<Path path={path} color="lightblue" />*/
      <Image
        image={image}
        fit="cover"
        x={0}
        y={0}
        width={imageSize}
        height={imageSize}
      />
    </Group>
  );
}
```

I would post an expo snack demoing it but react-native-skia wasnt working for me on expo but in the default react-native environment it worked like a charm

Comment: Okay I did some playing around on expo and now it draws the hexagons but sometimes `useImage` always return null but when the image does load it clips it properly

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/GEBaeB88j

Comment: Did some more playing around and now `useImage` works on Android and iOS but on the web it doesnt work when trying to load local files https://snack.expo.dev/5JTKu0o_X

Comment: The images are appears like as list in 2 column (20 images). On web it looks perfect with url(local images not appear on web). On simulator appears as list. Any help?

Comment: I noticed the same thing im trying to figure out whats going wrong

Comment: I think its an expo on skia thing because when i use it in bare react native project it works just fine